# Rails Routing: Flexible Resource Path depending on attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, custom-routes

How could you make a route for resource be flexible enough depending on its attributes?

For example,

```
resources :articles, param: :article_slug do
    member do
      resources :comments
    end
end
```

`Article` has attributes of `title, category, slug, etc`

But the client wants it that the category must be the first present in url, such as: `/entertainment/articles/:article_slug/comments/:id` or `/sports/articles/:article_slug/comments/:id`. I don't know what is the right approach for this one.

Comment: what url you have now? after run `rake routes`

Comment: I just have the `/articles/:article_slug/comments/:id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
scope path: ':category' do
  resources :articles, param: :article_slug do
      resources :comments
      end
  end
end
```

And generate the url in this way,

```
article_comment_path(@article, @comment, category: @article.category)
```

Comment: Yes, it could work but category is attribute of `Article`. I'm trying to use some lambda methods but it doesn't work.

Comment: @JoseMarieAntonioMiñoza I have update the answer, you can check it.